# HTML Sum of Column Needed

Tags: html, sum

I have the following html code for a table I am generating information from but I also need it to calculate the sum of the "TranAmt" column. Can someone help me with this?

```
<p>Hi Marly,</p>
<p>The following customer invoices were posted today:</p>
<table style="width: 1300px;" border="1" cellspacing="1.5" cellpadding="1.5"     align="left">
<thead>
<tr style="background-color: #81BEF7;" align="center" valign="middle">
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>Customer ID</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>Customer Name</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>Customer PO Number</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>Invoice Number</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>Invoice Date</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>Post Date</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>Invoice Amount</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>Invoice Sales Tax Amount</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><strong>Create User</strong></td>
</tr>
</thead>
{BEGIN*REPEAT}
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>{CustID}</td>
<td>{CustName}</td>
<td>{CustPONo}</td>
<td>{TranID}</td>
<td>{TranDate}</td>
<td>{PostDate}</td>
<td>{TranAmt}</td>
<td>{STaxAmt}</td>
<td>{CreateUserID}</td>
</tr>
{END*REPEAT}
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JQuery you can use the n-th child selector to add all the items of a column within a table.

http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Here's an example

```
var rows = $("#table_id tr:gt(0)");
rows.children("td:nth-child(7)").each(function() {
  the_sum += parseInt($(this).text()); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will help you for getting the total of any column whose column header name you supplied to it. But I want to suggest one thing instead of tag names thead and tbody plz use some id, as it will create problem if you have multiple tables in the same page.

```
function someFunction() {
    var invoiceTotalAmount = getTotal(("invoice amount").toUpperCase());
}

function getTotal(myString) {
  var CellListing = $("thead > tr > td");
  var selIndex=-1;
  var sum = 0;
  CellListing.each(function(index){
    if($(this).children("strong").html().toUpperCase()===myString)
       selndex= index+1;
   });

  var rows = $("tbody >tr");
  rows.children("td:nth-child("+selIndex+")").each(function() {
    sum += parseInt($(this).text()); 
  });
  return sum;
}
```

running example [html sum of column needed](http://jsbin.com/orufus/68/edit)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to define variable in `{FinalTranAmt}` so i'm explain you
Tack a variable with initially 0 as value 
For every repeat add `{TranAmt}` in `{FinalTranAmt}` & finally print it.
I don't know my structure is right or not.

```
{FinalTranAmt} = 0;
{BEGIN*REPEAT}
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>{CustID}</td>
<td>{CustName}</td>
<td>{CustPONo}</td>
<td>{TranID}</td>
<td>{TranDate}</td>
<td>{PostDate}</td>
<td>{TranAmt}</td>
<td>{STaxAmt}</td>
<td>{CreateUserID}</td>
</tr>
{FinalTranAmt} += {TranAmt} ;
{END*REPEAT}
```